# React navigation 6 headerRight truncated if title is too long

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I updated my application to React Navigation 6.
In all of my screens I customised the `headerBackImage`, and added some `headerRight` with a Text.
In React Navigation 5, if the `headerTitle` was too long, it's was directly truncated and ... was added at the end of title like this :

[image]

But in React navigation 6, it's look like this feature changed. I added some backgroundColor to show you the cutting of th Header :

[image]

I saw that topic : [React Native Navigation Header title too long, ends up overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356519/react-native-navigation-header-title-too-long-ends-up-overflowing), but maybe there is a new props added in V6.

Here is my screen :

```js
<ProfileStack.Screen
    options={({ navigation }: ScreenProps) => ({
        headerTitle: 'My header title is not truncated why ?',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            backgroundColor: EColors.rouge,
        },
        headerBackImage: () => (
            <BackButton />
        ),
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerBackTitle: ' ',
        headerRight: () => (
            <Text
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('toOtherScreen')}
                style={{ marginRight: 20, backgroundColor: EColors.vert }}
            >
                Infos
            </Text>
        ),
    })}
    name="screenName"
    component={ComponentName}
/>
```

Did someone encounter that in RN V6?